# Does proximity to a fire station affect building flammability?

Tags: simcity-2013

In prior installations of the Simcity series, the main factor in the flammability of a building was proximity to a fire station. In this version of Simcity, it is not immediately clear whether this is a factor at all. However, it does seem clear that education level has a bearing on building flammability.

So my question is, **does proximity to a fire station have any bearing on building flammability, or is it only driven by education?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct proximity to a fire station without a martial does nothing to prevent fires. However, it is also not only impacted by education.

Buildings visited by a fire marshal are immune to fires for a time.

Abandoned buildings, and built up garbage can also lead to increased fires.

Comment: Accumulation of garbage also increases the likelyhood of fire.

Comment: So just a No should be added as an answer some where as the building does not help. If you build the upgraded station and send out the marshal then there -might- be some relationship just because the AI that moves the marshal around is stupid.